# SQL database Error Java EE 6

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jboss6.x

I'm using IDE eclipse Helios ,MySQL 5.1, Jboss 6.0. When i try to open Perspective  " Database Development" . I've got this error in my Java EE project :

Could not create the view: Plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result.internal.ui.view.ResultsView.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Hard to say. Reinstall your Eclipse and try again.

Comment: Why cant you update sqltools plugin again? Try for it, good luck!

Comment: Okey i will . Thaanks man

Comment: already Tried to update but i still have the same problem !

Comment: Fixed by Reinstalling and Update .